# Delphi IdHTTPServer (Indy 10.6): retrive some request/response info from TIdTCPConnection in OnWorkEnd event

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

It is possible retrieve some info (for logging purpose) from TIdTCPConnection when OnWorkEnd event is fired by TIdContext.Connection?

I want info like:
    - User ip-address (found my self in Socket.Binding.PeerIP)
    - Browser/client user agent
    - DateTime start request
    - Total size of request
    - Byte send
    - Filename of the file send

My server is very simple, on each request, response with a filestream.

```
procedure TMyHttpServer.OnCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
     AResponseInfo.ContentStream   := TFileStream.Create('C:\server\file.exe', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
     AContext.Connection.OnWorkEnd := MyOnWorkEnd;
end;


procedure TMyHttpServer.MyOnWorkEnd(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
var
    aConnection : TIdTCPConnection;
    aIPAddress, aFileName, aDateStart, aByteSend, aFileSize, aUserAgent : string;
    aDateEnd   : TDateTime;
begin
    aConnection := TIdTCPConnection(ASender);

    aIPAddress := aConnection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;

    aFileName  := ''; // Filename download 
    aDateStart := ''; // Date start download
    aDateEnd   := Now; 
    aByteSend  := ''; // byte send
    aFileSize  := ''; // file size
    aUserAgent := ''; // user agent

    WriteLog(aFileName  + ' ' + aDateStart +' '+aDateEnd +' etc.');

end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request and response info are not directly accessible in the `OnWork...` events.  You will have to pass around the information manually.  I would suggest either:

1. Derive a new class from `TFileStream` to store the desired info, and then process the info in the class's destructor when the server frees the `ContentStream` after the response transfer is finished.
2. Derive a new class from `TIdServerContext` to hold pointers to the `TIdHTTPRequestInfo` and `TIdHTTPResponseInfo` objects:

   ```
   type
     TMyContext = class(TIdServerContext)
     public
       Request: TIdHTTPRequestInfo;
       Response: TIdHTTPResponseInfo;
     end;
   ```

   Then you can assign that class type to the server's `ContextClass` property before activating the server, and typecast the `AContext` parameter in the `OnCommandGet` event to your class type so you can assign its pointers, and assign the `AContext` object to the `AContext.Connection.Tag` property:

   ```
   MyHttpServer.ContextClass := TMyContext;

   ...

   procedure TMyHttpServer.OnCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
   begin
     TMyContext(AContext).Request := ARequestInfo;
     TMyContext(AContext).Response := AResponseInfo;
     AContext.Connection.Tag := NativeInt(AContext);
     //...
   end;
   ```

   In the `OnWork...` events, you can then type-cast the `Sender` parameter to  reach its `Tag`, and type-cast that to your custom class to reach its stored request/response pointers:

   ```
   procedure TMyHttpServer.MyOnWorkEnd(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
   var
     aConnection : TIdTCPConnection;
     aContext: TMyContext;
     //...
   begin
     aConnection := TIdTCPConnection(ASender);
     aContext := TMyClass(aConnection.Tag);
     //...
   end;
   ```
3. A slight variation of #2 would be to manipulate the `Self` pointer of the `OnWorkEnd` event handler to pass the `Context` object directly to the handler without using the `Connection.Tag` property:

   ```
   type
     TMyContext = class(TIdServerContext)
     public
       Request: TIdHTTPRequestInfo;
       Response: TIdHTTPResponseInfo;
       MyServer: TMyHttpServer;
     end;

   ...

   procedure TMyHttpServer.OnCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
   var
     Handler: TWorkEndEvent;
   begin
     TMyContext(AContext).Request := ARequestInfo;
     TMyContext(AContext).Response := AResponseInfo;
     TMyContext(AContext).MyServer := Self;
     Handler := MyOnWorkEnd;
     TMethod(Handler).Data := TMyContext(AContext);
     AContext.Connection.OnWorkEnd := Handler
     //...
   end;

   procedure TMyHttpServer.MyOnWorkEnd(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
   var
     aConnection : TIdTCPConnection;
     aContext: TMyContext;
     aServer: TMyHttpServer;
     //...
   begin
     aConnection := TIdTCPConnection(ASender);
     aContext := TMyClass(Self);
     aServer := aContext. MyServer;
     //...
   end;
   ```

Comment: please, you can explain me this line `AContext.Connection.Tag := NativeInt(AContext);`. I don't undestand, What for?

Comment: The `TIdContext.Connection` property is a `TIdTCPConnection` object, which is a `TComponent` descendant. The [`TComponent.Tag`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Tag) property is a free-form property, you can put whatever value you want in it. It is a `NativeInt`, so it is large enough to hold a pointer (assigning an object pointer to a `Tag` is very common). The `OnWorkEnd` event does not have direct access to `AContext`, so I'm assigning `AContext` to the Connection's `Tag` and then retrieving it later in the same Connection's `OnWorkEnd` event.

Comment: Perfect! thank you! you are my hero! i see your name in comment of Indy component! great work!

Comment: Use tag property in this way is safe (for performance/security)? Is a good practice?

Comment: @SimoneNigro. Yes, it is safe. The RTL/VCL/FMX do not use it for anything, it is meant for developers to use however they want, per the documentation: "*Tag has no predefined meaning. The Tag property can store any additional integer value for the convenience of developers. Often, Tag stores a pointer. A Tag value can be typecast to the appropriate pointer type. Notice that on 64-bit platforms, all  pointer types are 8 bytes in size, while on 32-bit platforms, pointer types are 4 bytes. These pointer sizes correspond to sizes of NativeInt integral values on 64-bit and 32-bit platforms.*"

Comment: @SimoneNigro: That being said, the `OnWork...` events can be fired for both reading and writing operations, and a `TIdContext` can be re-used for multiple requests from the same client connection, so I would suggest updating the `OnWorkEnd` handler to only perform its logic if the `AWorkMode` parameter is `wmWrite` (the server is sending data to the client, not the other way around). It might also be a good idea to reset `Connection.OnWorkEnd` to nil at the top of `OnCommandGet` and then set it back to `MyOnWorkEnd()` only if `ContentStream` is assigned data that needs to be logged.